# SQL Subquery to Return Nth Highest Salary along with Name, City, etc

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Apologies for posting a question similar to one that has been asked many times.  I could not find another thread that would return other fields along with the salary field.  My SQL is below, I just replace the 3 with whichever number I am looking or.  However, I am not sure how to also return the Name, Age, and City fields from tblPerson.  I know there needs to be a subquery of some sort but I have not been able to figure it out.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thank you in advance!

```
Select TOP 1 Salary 
FROM
    (Select DISTINCT TOP 3 Salary
     FROM tblPerson
     Order By Salary DESC) Result
ORDER BY Salary
```

Comment: Let me know if my solution work or throws error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply add what you want the subquery to return into the select clause to have the columns you want to be included in the `result` table. But also remember to include these columns on the outer query so they appear in your final result. like such:

```
Select TOP 3 result.salary, result.name, result.age, result.city
FROM
     (Select DISTINCT TOP 3 tblPerson.salary, tblPerson.name, 
      tblPerson.age,tblPerson.city
      FROM tblPerson
      Order By Salary DESC) result
ORDER BY Salary
```

your `result` table from your subquery looks like this:

```
salary  name       age  city
90000   Mr.derp    21   Minneapolis
80000   Ms.herp    52   St.Paul
70000   Mr.blah    89   Fakecity
```

It has 3 rows cause of the keyword `TOP 3` and the columns as the result of `tblPerson.salary, tblPerson.name, tblPerson.age,tblPerson.city` in the `select` clause. Then we can simply select from this table with the outer query.

You can use `select *` if you want every columns or specify whichever column you want with the column name. You can change `n` in `TOP n` to see how many rows you want to select from the top.

Comment: This will not return ties, however.

Comment: You could use rank() to get the ties

Answer (score 0):

Didn't try it on machine but let me know result/error of this :

```
Select TOP 1 a.Salary, a.Name, a.Age, a.City 
FROM
tblPerson a
inner join
 (Select DISTINCT TOP 3 Salary
  FROM tblPerson
  Order By Salary DESC
 )Result
on a.Salary = Result.Salary
ORDER BY a.Salary
```

Answer (score 0):

I see other answers using the select top approach. I would be more inclined to this, but just personal preference.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *
    ,Row_Number() OVER(ORDER BY Salary DESC) AS rown
    FROM tblPerson
) AS x WHERE rown = '3'
```

The row number is assigned to each row in the table, ordered by salary. You can then use the where to pick the nth row, in this case salary.

To get a list of all records which match an nth salary:

```
SELECT * FROM tblPerson as p
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Salary FROM(
        SELECT Salary
        ,Row_Number() OVER(ORDER BY Salary DESC) AS rown
        FROM tblPerson
    ) AS x1 WHERE rown = '3'
) AS x2 on x2.salary = p.salary
```

Comment: That's a good call, I just ran into an issue however.  What if I want to pick out the 4th highest salary for instance but if there are multiple people that have the same salary I want to return all of them?

Comment: @Chuck0185 This could be achieved using the Row_Number() method, but would require a join. I can edit in an example, but the solution by O.KOO may be more succinct.